# Join table to a subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, amazon-redshift

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824778/max-stage-using-timestamp-sql-redshift/53827075#53827075) someone helped me with a subquery.  Now I'd like to add to the query but am getting an error message.  (I'm still learning rules around subqueries.)

Updated SQL below.  The error is:

> ```
> [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "application_stages";
> ```

```
SELECT t1.*, applications.status, applications.stage_name
FROM application_stages t1
JOIN (
    select application_id, max(exited_on) as exited_on
    from application_stages 
    group by application_id
) t2 
USING (application_id,exited_on)
join applications on application_stages.application_id = applications.id
where application_id in ('91649746', '91991364', '96444221')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign aliases, you need to consistently use them in all clauses and to avoid ambiguity of same named columns in other tables. Consider following adjustment

```
SELECT s.*, a.status, a.stage_name
FROM application_stages s
JOIN (
    select application_id, max(exited_on) as exited_on
    from application_stages 
    group by application_id
) m 
USING (application_id, exited_on)
JOIN applications a ON a.application_id = s.id
WHERE a.application_id IN ('91649746', '91991364', '96444221')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions for this:

```
select ast.*, a.status, a.stage_name
from (select ast.*,
             rank() over (partition by application_id order by exited_on desc) as seqnum
      from application_stages ast
     ) ast join
     applications a
     on ast.application_id = a.id
where ast.seqnum = 1 and
      ast.application_id in ('91649746', '91991364', '96444221');
```

Your query has several issues:

- `application_id` in the `where` is ambiguous
- `application_stages` has the alias `t1`, so the former is not recognized

Note that if `application_id` is a number (which I'm guessing is the case), then the constants should not have single quotes).

Comment: Thanks, @Gordon Linoff.  Is it possible to tweak my original query without rewriting into a windows function? I'll add the table name to application_id and remove the single quotes from the application_ids.

Comment: @WilsonS . . . Window functions are much recommended for this.